# Some action can not be parsed for verified contract

Tags: gnosis-safe

During the interaction with our smart contract (arb1:0xC7b58c32A2756921BDAe6d9f9a575cd217104b22) using Safe, some actions cannot be correctly parsed. arb1:0x48Aadfc0a41Df3df0f7abC72352eED567f74562e is our Safe address, and you can refer to the transaction with nonce: 1. Our smart contract is open-sourced, and some interaction actions can be parsed normally. We appreciate your assistance. Thank you.